# DataTables: search all columns when server-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm using [IgnitedDatatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki) (CodeIgniter library) for [DataTables](http://datatables.net). The table gets generated without problems but if I search/filter it can only filter one column at a time. If I set "bServerSide" to false it works but then I lose the server-side functionality.

In the examples, this one is working:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html

while this isn't (server-side):
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Is this not possible to achieve when running server-side?

This is my JSON response (shortened and with replaced data):

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":45438,"iTotalDisplayRecords":45438,"aaData":[["abc","12345","example@example.com","","","2010-01-27 22:31:10","Edit<\/a> Delete<\/a>"],["abc2"," test123","test@test.com","","","2008-06-15 22:09:33","Edit<\/a> Delete<\/a>"]],"sColumns":"fname,lname,email,phone,cellphone,created,edit"}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("#members").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    'sAjaxSource': '<?php echo base_url();?>members/listener',
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": 'POST',
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        } );
    },
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
        { "sName": "fname", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
        { "sName": "lname", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
        { "sName": "email", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
        { "sName": "phone", "sWidth": "80px", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
        { "sName": "cellphone", "sWidth": "100px", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
        { "sName": "created", "sWidth": "120px", "aTargets": [ 5 ] },
        { "bSortable": false, "sName": "edit", "sWidth": "115px",   "aTargets": [ 6 ] }
    ]
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem if you filter server side is that you are filtering through an SQL query and this is what is written on the [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) you posted;

> - Filtering
> - NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
> - word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
> - on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited

Basically you could do what you want to do (a regular expression match an all columns) but it's going to kill the performance server side.

What i usually do is provide a filter for each column, i need to filter.